# Comma separated cell into different columns

Tags: python, pandas

[image]
Reproduceable dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame({'(Source,Target,Weight)':['Majed Moqed,Majed Moqed,0']})
How do I split so that each comma separated element in the columns becomes the column head to the corresponding comma separated element in the rows?

Expected output

```
Source       Target      Weight
```

Majed Moqed    Majed Moqed      0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
col = '(Source,Target,Weight)'
df = pd.DataFrame(df[col].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=col[1:-1].split(','))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        Source       Target Weight
0  Majed Moqed  Majed Moqed      0
```

---

**Even better,** create the desired DataFrame directly from `edgelist`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(edgelist, columns=['Source', 'Target', 'Weight'])
```